# Ctrl+a and Ctrl+e not working when logged in as user?

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I'm taking baby steps trying to automate setting up a VPS running debian with everything in place to run [elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/).

Creating the new user like this:

```
PASSWORD=my_chosen_password
/usr/sbin/useradd -m deployer
echo deployer:$PASSWORD | chpasswd
su -c "mkdir /home/deployer/.ssh" deployer #create .ssh folder as deployer
su -c "touch /home/deployer/.ssh/authorized_keys" deployer
cat /root/.ssh/authorized_keys >> /home/deployer/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

When I login as root all is well.

```
ssh root@139.59.135.214
root@holidaymachine:~#
```

But when I login as deployer on that same machine:

```
ssh deployer@139.59.135.214
$:~#
```

And I'm unable to use "ctrl+a ctrl+e" and who knows what else I'm missing out on.. hitting up arrow trying to access command history gives me `^[[A`.

I found the question ["Ctrl + A doesn't work in Bash Terminal on OS X Lion"](https://superuser.com/questions/316668/ctrl-a-doesnt-work-in-bash-terminal-on-os-x-lion), compared `set -o` logged in as root with settings for deployer, changed them as deployer to match root.. but am running in to:

```
$ set -o history
-sh: 4: set: Illegal option -o history
```

Any suggestions on where to keep looking?

Answer (score 2):

Add `-s /bin/bash` when creating a new user:

```
/usr/sbin/useradd -m -s /bin/bash deployer
```

#### Backtracking:

I managed to show Usage & Options for useradd, by running it without any input.

```
useradd
```

... noticed `-s, --shell SHELL login shell of the new account`

... looked for more information about `-s/--shell` and found:
[add users in linux](https://www.tecmint.com/add-users-in-linux/)

...which led me to `cat /etc/passwd`

Where I saw that root has `/bin/bash`.